# AutoHotKey: Getting a chord to set off a hotstring

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, chord

I use thousands of AHK hotstrings. For example (simplified):

```
::btw::by the way
```

Unlike most AHK users, the only endkey I allow is `\`. So when I type `btw\`, I get `by the way`. Space or enter or other such keys do *not* set off the hotstrings. This ensures that hotstrings are never set off unintentionally.

Now, I also use chords. Here's a simplified version of one my chords:

```
~t & g::
~g & t::
    SendInput {Backspace}
    SendInput {Space}the{Space}
    Return
```

The way these chords work is that if I press my finger on the border between the `t` and `g` keys, AHK types `the` (Including a space before and after.) Very useful.

**Now, I'd like to take this up a notch:** I want chords to automatically set off hotstrings. For example, say I want to type `by the way the`. I could type `btw\` and then `t` and `g` together. But, it would be nicer if I could skip the backslash, and instead have the chord automatically set off the hotstring. (Only in the case where the text immediately before a chord is a hotstring, of course.)

Now obviously, I want this to work not only for this specific combination of `btw` and `t`+`g`, but for any combination of hotstring and chord from my vast collection.

**How can I do that?**

(One idea that came to mind is that AHK probably has a function that it launches every time you hit an endkey, which does something to the effect of "Look at the text that the user typed so far. Is it a hotstring? If so execute it." If only I had a way to invoke that function from inside my chord script, that would solve my problem. However, I have no idea how to do that.)

Comment: Have you considered, simply making the hotstrings fire immediately rather than waiting for an end character? `:*:btw::by the way`

Comment: @MCL The problem with that is that then I'll need to be much more careful in what I use as a hotstring. I currently use `q` for `question`, and that would be out of the question. It will also make me unable to do hotstrings that contain each other like `il2` and `il2k`. (Which are `I'd like to ` and `I'd like to know `.)

Comment: I am very interested in this conversation, since I too use \, but also =,[,],/ as exit characters. Each exit character is for a specific language (spoken or programming).... Keep on going with the suggestions and keep us informed about the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending about 10 hours on it, I've decided to abandon this project. Besides all the usual AHK horribleness and bugs, there's the intractable problem that if I type `I love the sun` and then `7` and `u` at the same time, I'll get `I love the Sunday and` instead of `I love the sun and`, because AutoHotKey has no way of knowing I didn't mean it to expand the hotstring in that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question bothered me so much, I played around until I found a solution that seems to work pretty well:

```
#HotString *B0
SendMode, Input

endChars := "`n `t"
interruptChars := chr(8) ; 8 is BACKSPACE
counter := 33
while(counter <= 126)
{
    interruptChars .= chr(counter++)
}
Loop, Parse, endChars
{
    Hotkey, *~%A_LoopField%, FinishHotstring
}
Loop, Parse, interruptChars
{
    Hotkey, *~%A_LoopField%, InterruptHotString
}

; this is our pending hotstring replacement
pendingHS := ""
; this var will hold the number of BACKSPACEs needed
; to erase the input before replacing the hotstring
pendingBS := -1

Exit

::btw::
    pendingHS := "by the way"
    RegExMatch(A_ThisLabel, ":.*?:(.*)", abbr)
    pendingBS := StrLen(abbr1)
return

::bt::
    pendingHS := "Bluetooth"
    RegExMatch(A_ThisLabel, ":.*?:(.*)", abbr)
    pendingBS := StrLen(abbr1)
return

~t & g::
~g & t::
    if(pendingHS) {
        pendingBS++
        Send % "{BACKSPACE " pendingBS "}" pendingHS " the "
        pendingHS := ""
    } else {
        Send % "{BACKSPACE} the "
    }
Return

FinishHotstring:
    if(pendingHS) {
        pendingBS++
        Send, % "{BACKSPACE " pendingBS "}" pendingHS
        pendingHS := ""
    }
return

InterruptHotString:
    if(pendingHS) {
        pendingHS := ""
    }
return
```

Sadly, this solution removes itself very far from the AHK standard for hotstrings. At the beginning, you'll have to define your custom `endChars`, and also your custom `interruptChars` (they tell the script when your hotstring isn't actually one, since it is triggered immediately). I used BACKSPACE and ASCII chars 33 through 126.
The rest is quite self-explanatory: Every alleged hotstring is stored and not yet sent. If either an `endChar` or a `chord` or an `interruptChar` is triggered, the script either sends the usual hotstring replacement or adds the chord appendix or doesn't do anything.

**Please discuss!**

Comment: Isn't `abbr` and `abbr1` a typo? On one hand it looks that way, on the other hand, the script is working...

Comment: @RamRachum pleaser refer to [RegExMatch()](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm).  "If any capturing subpatterns are present inside NeedleRegEx, their matches are stored in an array whose base name is OutputVar. For example, if the variable's name is Match, the substring that matches the first subpattern would be stored in Match1, the second would be stored in Match2, and so on."

Comment: I see. This solution is impressive. But... I don't know whether I want to diverge so much from how AHK does hotstrings. I have my own customizations to hotstrings and now I'll have to ensure that these still work when combined with yours...

Comment: I just wish AHK would simply give us access into its internal routine which does the "Is this a hotstring? If so execute it" dance, so we wouldn't have to hack around it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a drag. What customizations are you talking about? Basically, you just need to set `pendingHS` to whatever you want to be output when an `endChar` is fired. Transforming your script in case of auto-replacement hotstrings is trivial, complex hotstrings would mean a little work.

Comment: I've got 2 customizations: The first is a function that calculates how much backspacing is needed. (e.g. in `btw` you don't have to delete the first `b`, in `Py`->`Python` you don't have to delete at all.) The second shows a toaster message with all the hotstrings that contain this hotstring, so I'll be aware of their existence in case I forgot.

Comment: I would want so bad for this all thing to be in Python so I could work with a normal language... AHK is so bad. But as far as I know there isn't a powerful enough package for this in Python.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, this comment was nonsense.

Comment: I'll probably give your solution a try. I just need time to emotionally accept it :)

Comment: Working on this problem inspired me to create this: http://i.imgur.com/YmQaIQ1.png

Answer (score 0):

Using [RegEx Powered Dynamic Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/) may be an option for you.  The tricky part would be determining whether the text is a hotstring or not.  Possibly keeping an array of everything?  Below is some pseudo-code.

```
#Include DynamicHotstrings.ahk

hotstrings("(\w+)\\", "check")
Return

check:
    args := $1
    if (args = "btw") ; Ideally you would check an array to see if this was a hotstring
        msgbox % args ; SendInput
return
```

Getting the hotstrings into an array could be simply maintaining them manually, parsing your script, or even using a script like [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/93889-hotkey-help-display-ahk-active-hotkeys-and-hotstrings/).

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't really understand how that would solve my problem. Do you suggest that when the user hits a chord, I'll manually go to `check`? If so, how will it have access to the typed text?

Comment: @RamRachum `check` will be called for every `Word` you enter. If the word is a hotstring, you could store it, and the next chord you trigger could send the corresponding string. The problem here is, that you would have to define some kind of timeout in order to determine whether the user wants to append a "chord hotstring" or just send the hotstring replacement itself. Also, @ElliotDeNolf: You can simply check for an existing hotstring via [IsLabel()](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#IsLabel). You can then send the replacement text: `Send, ::btw`

Comment: Wow, a very useful function that I didn't know about, thanks!